# Is it possible for Laravel to execute a Job without the "job" property in the payload?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel to consume jobs from an external service, using RabbitMQ queue driver.

Each job payload is basically a serialized object.

However, it seems to me that Laravel requires jobs to have a property called "job" that maps to a fully qualified class name (FQCN). But I can't do that since these jobs are created on a service which doesn't even know my Laravel app.

Is it possible for me to consume and execute a job without having this property?

Example:

Is it possible for Laravel to execute a job containing this payload:

```
{
    "fooBar": "abc-123",
    "baz": false,
    "bazBar": 1
}
```

Instead of this:

```
{
    "job": "Acme\\\\Jobs\\\\FooJob",
    "data": {
        "fooBar": "abc-123",
        "baz": false,
        "bazBar": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without overriding some of the methods within Laravel's job dispatcher. Laravel's queue system is designed only to be used with Laravel, so the structure of the payload into the queue is the format it expects. If you want to consume the queued job with another framework you have a number of options.

1) Ignore the FQCN in the job payload. However, you'll be tying yourself to the structure of Laravel's job payload and it could break your app if this ever changes.

2) Override Laravel's job dispatcher to change the data structure it passes off to the queue. This seems like more hassle than it's worth.

3) Write your own job dispatcher and interact with the queue system with your own classes. This gives you complete control over how you use the queue.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is any library that implements a more generic job dispatcher like you said in #3?