# Writing custom Laravel queue driver

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mqtt, message-queue, laravel-5.5

I'm in the process of writing a custom Laravel 5.5 queue driver for interacting with MQTT. I'm using the [Mosquitto MQTT extension](https://mosquitto-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

There's not a lot of documentation on how to implement this. What has me stuck is understanding the expected payload. When my `pop()` method is being called, and my `MqttJob` class is being processed, I receive an error about a missing index `'job'`. I've tried looking at the implentation of various other drivers including Redis, Beanstalkd, and other custom drivers like for [Kafka](https://github.com/rapideinternet/laravel-queue-kafka), and [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq), but still see where their implementations follow this expected payload structure.

If anyone has experience or understanding of how the queues, workers and jobs interact, it'd be much appreciated.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709846/is-it-possible-for-laravel-to-execute-a-job-without-the-job-property-in-the-pa?rq=1) is similar to what I'm asking.

**UPDATE** I implemented the `getRawBody()` method, as:

```
public function getRawBody()
{
    return json_encode([
        'job'  => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call',
        'data' => [
            'commandName' => get_class($this),
            'command'     => serialize(clone $this),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

But now I'm getting the following error:

```
local.ERROR: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

I'm not sure what property of my `MqttJob` is a closure. The `clone` should be performing a shallow copy, and I haven't implemented the `__clone()` method.

Comment: plz try, if it's possible, to remove any $this occurence within the  getRawBody() function, and see if it give you the same error.